# How to get into character during a session?

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying

Through a couple of friends, I got a chance to participate in a one-shot campaign a while ago which I absolutely enjoyed. They did this for me and another person as a way to introduce us to D&D without any commitment. After liking it, they invited me to their campaign which I joined shortly after.

I created a necromancer wizard with a lawful evil alignment.

After getting used to the mechanics of the game and how it plays out, I really got to enjoy it. I still struggle a lot with actually role-playing though. My friends and I sometimes find ourselves into silly situations or just do goofy things that cause us to break out into laughter. The DM doesn't seem to mind and he himself cannot hold back from laughing at certain points.

It is probably fine for this to happen, but what I feel I lack in is finding composure and getting back to character. My wizard is lawful evil and I kind of based his creation on Dio from Jojo's (reference) who has a power seeking, narcissistic character. I usually start out fine when the session first starts, but when something happens that makes me laugh, I just cannot get back into roleplaying correctly. I am supposed to act aloof and evil, but as soon as I crack a smile I lose it.

In addition, I also have a hard time acting evil and lawful. How should someone (who is evil) act in a party that has good and neutral people in it? What can I do to play in character without disrupting the game or making it worse for others?

The solution I have found for now is that my introduction into the game was a result of the party breaking me out of a prison as a part of a quest. As a result, I pledged my loyalty despite them having different goals and ideals. My goal is to acquire power (political or economical) through any means necessary.

Any tips and advice would be appreciated!

Comment: First of all welcome to the site amd the hobby! Feel freeto take the [Tour] if you have questions.

Comment: About your question precisely, are you looking for hints on how to get back in character after a disruption or about how to play an evil character in a good party? If the former, how commited are you to the character? Because my knee jerk reaction would be to give advice on how to preemptively choose a roleplay that you can roleplay in a live game, but that would probably mean droping or changing the character.

Comment: @Jonathan: Please don't answer in comments; they don't have the quality assurance mechanisms that answers do. Wait for the question to be reopened, and then leave your answer as, well, an answer.

Comment: Is the actual question "what are some methods used to get into character or to role play a character?"

Comment: I feel like this is answerable. Not specifically in the "You should do x" format, but more along the lines of what is important to contribute to the game, and what contributes to a "character".

Comment: I believe this is too broad. You should limit it to one exact question: either getting back into character or playing an evil alignment.